# Override plugin text domain in child theme

Tags: plugins, child-theme, translation, localization

I have a plugin YITH Wishlist in use and I want to override their translation with my own translation which I have included in my child theme.

So basically I created this folder:
/mychildtheme/languages

and placed this file in it `yith-woocommerce-wishlist-de_DE.mo` / `yith-woocommerce-wishlist-de_DE.po`.

Within my functions.php I did the following:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'yith_load_textdomain' );
function yith_load_textdomain() {
    unload_textdomain( 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist' );
  load_plugin_textdomain( 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist', false, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/languages' );
}
```

But this has no effect. Does somebody knows how I can override a plugin text domain with my custom translations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to override a plugin text domain, create (if not exist) a folder named `languages` and another one `plugins` (in languages) in the wp-content folder.

This folders is intended, with the template and file hierarchy, to be load upon the other that could exist.

When you update a plugin, text domain that you modified and copied into this folder will not be erase. It's up to you to maintain it up to date.

Comment: Hello @benoti, I did that, but the changes are not visible on the frontend.

Comment: so you put yith-woocommerce-wishlist-de_DE.mo and yith-woocommerce-wishlist-de_DE.po in: wp-content\languages\plugins ?
I have done exactly that for the yith custom login plugin and it worked fine, so shouldn't be a problem with yith plugins. Make sure you remove your code from functions.php

Answer (score 0):

You should not be modifying a plug-in's text domain like that. It forces you to have to change it over and over again each time the plugin updates.

If it does not already have it, create a folder `/languages` in the plugin's directory. In there place a file that contains all the translated text that matches the code you specify in your `wp-config.php` file. A program like [Poedit](https://poedit.net/download) will help you do this.

Comment: When I do that - add a folder to the plugins directory - it will be deleted once I update the plugin...?